# Android can not get version name, return String null

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

First of all sorry for my English, I am a new android developer (hobbies) and I have a problem.

I am sorry but I do not know how to do a better description of my issue. Inded, since 3 days I try to fix this issue but I have no more idea.

I believe to think android studio is crazy, or its probably to me.

So in my project, I have tried to implement an auto update system but to do that I already achieve the part to get the version from my text on server.

But since I have implement the code to get the current version of my app "app name", I have the same error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{erim.ups/erim.ups.PreLoadScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2361)
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
>                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
>                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
>                                                               at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:156)
>                                                               at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:110)
>                                                               at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:222)
>                                                               at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.(AlertDialog.java:452)
>                                                               at erim.ups.PreLoadScreen.**(PreLoadScreen.java:44)**
>                                                               at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510) 
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
>                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
>                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

But the line 44 is to declare sharedPreferences, I dont understand what is my problem.

> final SharedPreferences data = this.getSharedPreferences("Mes_Parametres", MODE_PRIVATE);

**Could you please help me ?**

Link of my source: [preloadScreen.java](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99807456/temp/PreLoadScreen.java.html)

Comment: don't link your source code to other website while asking questions, try to put it in same question snippet

Comment: Sorry, that was the first and the lzst time i did this mistake.

Comment: Tip: Use Github for code instead of Dropbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, do not call methods that you inherit from `Activity` until after `super.onCreate()` has been called in the `onCreate()` method.

Replace:

```
final SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Mes_Parametres", MODE_PRIVATE); 
final SharedPreferences data = this.getSharedPreferences("Mes_Parametres", MODE_PRIVATE); 
final String monParametreUrl = data.getString("ParametreUrl", null);
```

with:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs; 
SharedPreferences data; 
String monParametreUrl;
```

Then, change your `onCreate()` to:

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
  sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Mes_Parametres", MODE_PRIVATE); 
  data = this.getSharedPreferences("Mes_Parametres", MODE_PRIVATE); 
  monParametreUrl = data.getString("ParametreUrl", null); 

  setContentView(R.layout.activity_pre_load_screen); 

  // rest of your onCreate() code goes here
}
```

Also, in the future, when you ask a question here on Stack Overflow, please put the relevant source code **in the question**, rather than as a link. After all, as soon as you delete that file in DropBox, your question can no longer help other developers nearly as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help, sadly your solution just change the error message now I have:                                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object                                                                                                       'For the line with : SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;'
PS: i didn t know for source, i gonna change that for future post